# Accessing Google Drive

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I want to access my google drive, display in the web browser the list of files in my drive. I also want to provide an option of viewing the contents of the file in the browser and download the file to the my local server(WAMP) and store its contents in a DB. Is there a way to do this only using PHP? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Google provides a REST API for Google Drive. They even provide a Quickstart Tutorial for PHP linked [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/php).